# Clear emails automatically from sent folder?

Tags: outlook.com

I managed to set to clear emails automatically for inbox (after the email is redirected somewhere) using Inbox rule, but how to set this for Sent folder as well? I'm not familiar with Outlook.com and can't figure out a way to create a "Sent" rule.

Answer (score 0):

We have a reference article located at https://support.appliedi.net/kb/a1345/how-to-keep-messages-from-being-saved-to-sent-items-folder-in-outlook-2013-2016.aspx which addresses this question.  For the visibility of the relevant content to answer the question is as follows:

Outlook.com / Outlook Web App (OWA) is intended for those on the go.  Email can be accessed from anywhere.  The account can be connected to some of your favorite apps such as Skype.  It does, however, have limited features.  The OWA is a "compact" edition of sorts.  Rule settings only apply to the Inbox.  Retention policy settings (OWA for business) appear to reflect the Inbox only as well.  Therefore rules cannot be specified to the Sent Items folder in OWA currently.

If you have Outlook 2013/2016 (not OWA), there are more features to help you manage your account settings.  In Outlook 2013/2016, you would not need to create a rule that deletes messages from the sent folder.  There is an option to not save sent messages at all.  After you connect your email account in Outlook 2013/2016.  The following steps can be used for this option.

*Please note that there is also an option to save sent messages.  Then archive/delete them after a time frame of your choosing.  The following steps do not include this option.*

1. Go to File>Options
2. Select Mail from the left column.
3. Scroll to "Save Messages"
4. Deselect the box "Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder"
5. Click OK

[image: Outlook 2013/2016 Sent Folder Selection Option]

You should never see a message in the Sent Items folder for this mailbox afterward. Repeat the steps for other mailboxes where applicable.

Comment: Please disclose your link to the website/product, as mentioned in the site FAQ.

Comment: Tombull89 - The posted answer is regarding differences between Microsoft.com which is Microsoft's online web application for email and Outlook full version 2013/2016 installs.  The question Nur presented specifying Outlook.com.  
I am not certain the website/product or FAQ in question.  Please clarify the FAQ in reference if this comment does not answer the question.  We are Applied Innovations.  We are Microsoft cloud hosting experts, who offer a variety of products and services for businesses.  Our website is https://www.appliedi.net/.  Please let us know if this addresses your request.